# Skiing in the French Alps - by Van

Tags: france, automobiles, alps, skiing

My brother has a Ford Transit which is spacious and comfortable. Our plan is to drive from London to an as yet undetermined ski resort in the French Alps. We plan to pay for parking in one of the resorts (around 15 euros per day) and sleep in the van for two - three nights.

My question is - what is the best French alps resort for our purpose? The car park needs to be near the slopes, obviously, or there should be a free shuttle bus to take us from the car park to the slopes. Also, a drive not exceeding 12 hours would be great. Do we need to book the car park in advance?

Any suggestions, and does anyone see any flaw in our plan?

EDIT: Does anyone have any suggestions for places to take a shower either for free or cheaply? Perhaps the camp sites will accept a little bargaining and let us take a shower for a euro or two each?:-)

Comment: mmh... it's gonna be cold. I suppose you want to ski/snowboard, and in the night you are tired so the sleeping matters. Sleeping in the cold (or rather cold) might not be the best. Otherwise, this sounds totally feasible, usually most parkings have a shuttle service to the slopes or are within walking distance. You can even find a cheap campground in the valley and drive up every morning. There is no 'best' though, it just depends on the range of drive.

Comment: +1 to @Vince comment, I would be concerned about the temperature, too. But then again some people even camp in the wild in the winter. Since your vehicle isn't going to provide you with a lot of protection, I guess you need to make sure you have camping gear (sleeping bags, etc.) that's appropriate for low temperatures.

Comment: Hi guys, we have slept in -5 before no problem. Inflatable mattress + duvet + sleeping bags - if anything we were too hot!

Comment: I am sure it's doable but do keep in mind that temperatures can be lower in mountains, -10 and below is a real possibility.

Comment: even -20 to -30 are possible (but not very likely). something i want to add: I dont know about france, but in austria we often stay at small private bed&breakfasts which were like 15-20e/night pp. That is not much more than what you quoted in your question but you would gain the comfort of a real bed, a hot shower and a free meal

Comment: I am mostly concerned about being tired. sleeping at -10 is possible with the right gear but if your body is exhausted and produces little warmth even the best gear will not be that effective. I'm saying that because even sleeping on a correct mattress in a warm apartment I already found myself tired at the beginning of a tough day.

Comment: @Flo I don't think it would be easy to find such accommodation in French ski resorts, certainly not in the bigger ones. Going to Austria looks like a good idea to save money but it's quite a bit further, coming from England by road.

Comment: First rule for living on a parking is "don't be a Rom"... More on topic, the closest département from UK is Haute-Savoie (74). Chatel resort (wonderful) is full of british people because it's also the closest from Geneva airport. Savoie (73) is a bit further and then South Alps is quite far (there are small (?) resorts 1H from Nice I believe).

Comment: If you can choose which week(s) you'll go on holidays, I think the best moment is january. Most probably, there'll be plenty of snow AND few people in parkings, skiing, etc. As there are people from all over Europe coming to Alps (DE, BE, UK, DK, even S), there are [calendars of school vacations in Europe](http://www.lesambruneschatel.fr/decouvrir-chatel/calendrier-vacances-2013-2014-europe) that might be handy. Expect crowded and pricey resorts from 15/02 till 08/03

Answer (score 8):

If you are prepared to pay €15/day, you might just as well stay at a proper campsite (with toilets, water, etc.) I don't think booking car parks in advance is generally possible (never noticed it in the resorts I went to but I usually stay away from the biggest, most popular resorts) but it might be a good idea for campsites.

Some potentially useful websites:

- [Full list of campsites](http://www.savoie-mont-blanc.com/en/offre/recherche/campsites/3/~~~~~~/%28page%29/1) in Savoie and Haute-Savoie by the local tourist board (in English)
- [First-hand info](http://lsinzelle.free.fr/Stations/Stations.htm) about camping outside of commercial campsites in ski resorts (in French, info seems a bit old in many cases)
- [Winter campsites or “caravaneige” in 2013-2014](http://www.ausommet.fr/apres-ski-stations-montagne-caravaneige-massifs-alpes-du-nord/) (in French, the site also mentions many regular car parks where RV are accepted).

I have never done it myself but judging by these websites, it seems there are many options. I don't think the distance from London is going to help you choose either, most ski resorts in the Northern part of the French Alps should be reachable in 12 hours, the difference between the furthest and the nearest is probably not more than 1 or 2 hours.

Note that in France, municipalities can forbid camping or staying overnight on car parks if they see fit and I don't think than sleeping in a van instead of a RV makes a lot of difference.

Comment: Agreed, it seems they are all fairly close together.

Comment: also I think that beyond being forbidden, camping in parkings is sometimes prevented by low entry gates.

Comment: @Vince Very often, yes. Height between 1.9 and 2.1m I guess (I'm 1.9m tall so I'd have not*BOOM*iced 1.8m ones ^^). Even if a Ford Transit is lower than that, there'll be problems with Gendarmerie Nationale or town police (not a real police but they'll call the real one). 2 people at night on a parking is suspicious (and they don't bring as much money as other tourists: not OK with them). Engine on for hours for heating the vehicle will be heard from a distance at night.